# What microphone and wireless speaker to choose for large audiences

Tags: microphone, sound, speakers, recommendations, wireless

I often have to make business presentations to 30-40 people in rooms with no audio equipment. At the end of the week, my voice is almost lost .. so I had to come up with a solution to make my presentations more professional. I thought about a Bluetooth microphone + Bluetooth speaker like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013JZ183U) or [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011Q340B4) but for an unknown reason, none of my Bluetooth mics could be paired with a Bluetooth speaker !

I also thought about an integrated speaker + microphone system like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00378GEAM), but unfortunately, its doesn't work with Bluetooth and its way too expensive...

does anyone please have a solution or an idea that is portable , wireless and not very expensive for less than 60$ ?

Thank you,

Comment: No offense meant, but... what kind of business is this where 200$ is _way to expensive_ for a useful (and likely long-lasting) investment? Really, you won't get decent amplification for less that that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can’t pair a Bluetooth microphone and speaker is that Bluetooth has latency. You would speak and the sound that comes out of the speaker would be 1–2 seconds later, like an echo. Bluetooth is a PC thing, not a pro audio thing. If you are playing music off an iPod through a Bluetooth speaker, the latency doesn’t matter. But in live performance, it does.

What you want is a “personal P.A. (Public Address) system” that is something like this:

[Pyle Pro PWMA200](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/853219-REG/pyle_pro_pwma200_wireless_rechargeable_portable.html)

Don’t be afraid to get something that is wired-only. Wired can be a feature in live performance because wireless can suffer from interference and you have to keep feeding the wireless transmitter batteries, which may expire part way through a performance. So wired is not necessarily worse. And for the same budget, you may get a much better quality wired solution.

Comment: I do think Bluetooth, as such, can get its latency a bit lower than a _second_, even though typical Bluetooth speakers may be in that range. But even 50 ms would be too much for a live-amplification application.